# Character seems to be colliding when colliders aren't actually touching.... - Unity Collision

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision-detection, collision

Basically, I noticed that for some reason, no collision was registered by `OnCollisionEnter2D` when a player jumped on a platform, even though the player seemed to be standing...
From far away the player seems to be colliding...(The white rectangle is the platform)

[image: From far away, he seems to be colliding]

But when we take a closer look, he actually isn't, even though the player isn't falling anymore : 
.
[image: Not touching]

This happens, even though the player falls down from a height ; he seemed to have collided (he stops) but tge `OnCollisionEnter2D`metjod, doesn't detect anything, and with a closer look, the player isn't actually touching... Video of that happenning : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Du6e.jpg)

Thank you to everyone to answers :)

Comment: Are you using RigidBody or CharacterController?

Comment: @Vakore Yes, a rigidbody...  :/ Im really stuck here, and I cant find the problem. Thanks for you response tho  This may also be a bug...

Comment: Have you tried unity/computer restart?

Comment: @Vakore I tried already restarting Unity... But not my computer...

Comment: Ill try when I come home today...